# Is is true that $\lim(\ln x) = \ln(\lim x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

As the title says, I want to ask everyone if $\lim(\ln x) = \ln(\lim x)$ when x approach to infinite with any function.

Comment: See how you can treat the infinite limit with a continuous function.

Comment: This is true if and only if the limit is taken as $x\to a$ for some positive real $a$ (assuming real variables and real-valued functions here). It's just the statement that $x\mapsto \ln x$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln(x)=\infty$$
$$\ln\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\right)=\infty$$
If I understood what you were saying properly, it was a bit unclear..

Comment: This is wrong. One doesn't say "$\ln \infty=\infty$".

Comment: I can accept the first line, just not the second one. Even after the edit, it's the same thing. $\ln \lim_{x\to\infty}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What do you think the domain of $\ln$ is? And what do you think the image is?

Comment: It's wrong to write "$\ln \infty$", let alone assign it a value.

Comment: I agree that instead of $\ln(\infty)$ one should say $\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln(x)$

Comment: @MPW : I agree with you there is a problem. If you extend $\ln  : (0,\infty) \to (-\infty,+\infty)$ to  $\ln :  (0,\infty) \cup \{0, + \infty\} \to (-\infty,\infty) \cup \{-\infty, + \infty\}$ such that $\ln( 0) = -\infty, \ln (+\infty) = +\infty$, then $\ln $ will stay continuous at the boundary, such that what the OP stated is true

Comment: It's a little simpler to state by including the endpoints in the intervals; (the extension of) $\ln$ defines an increasing, continuous bijection $[0, +\infty] \to [-\infty, +\infty]$.

Answer (score 3):

The function $\ln x:\mathbb{R^{+}}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. So $\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R^{+}} \ \ \lim_{x\to x_0 }\ln x =\ln x_0=\ln\lim_{x\to x_0}x$.

Comment: to me $\mathbb{R}^+$ is $[0,\infty)$ while $(0,\infty)$ is $\mathbb{R}^{+*}$

Comment: I think $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}| \ x>0\right\}$ but i think it' s clear.